# Ajuda como salvar uma tabela

Tags: lua

Como salvar uma tabela em um `storage` ou `string`, e como eu faria para retorná-la?

Answer (score 1):

Existem uma infinidade de maneiras de resolver esse problema de serialização de tabelas e a wiki do lua-users.org tem uma boa lista de alternativas: http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization

Comment: Opa, valeu amigo realmente procurei e achei table.serialize e unserialize, mas valeu mesmo :).

Comment: @JoaoGabriel: Essas funções não fazem parte da  biblioteca pradrão. Talvez o ambiente lua que você usa tenha incluido elas.